# How to keep separate transitions in separate CSS classes from overriding each other?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have one CSS class that does handles rotational animation:

```
  .rotation {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
```

And a second class which handles linear animation:

```
.linear {
  transition-property: left, bottom;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

The problem, of course, is that while I am intending to apply these transition rules to different properties -- `transform` in one case and `left, bottom` in the other -- they are in fact overriding each other when both are applied to one element, such that whichever one is applied last is the one who wins for the value of `transition-property`, and the overridden property has no transition applied to it.

Is there any way to apply separate transition classes this way?

Comment: You could use different wrapper elements

Answer (score 6):

Define a new rule for elements with both classes:

```
.linear.rotation {
   transition-property: transform, left, bottom;
   transition-duration: 0.4s, 0.8s, 0.8s;
   transition-delay: 0, 0, 0;
}
```

Ensure this rule is placed after any existing rules for `.linear` and `.rotation`.

BTW, animating the `top/right/bottom/left` properties isn’t the best for performance - ideally use only `transform` because it avoids re-layouts which are expensive. You can use `translate`/`translateX`/`translateY` to achieve (visually) the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of properties is limited you can rely on CSS variables like below:

```css
/* main class to be added to all the elements*/
.transition {
  transition-property: left, bottom, transform, opacity, height;
  transition-duration: var(--l-dur, 0s), var(--b-dur, 0s), var(--t-dur, 0s), var(--o-dur, 0s), var(--h-dur, 0s);
  transition-delay: var(--l-del, 0s), var(--b-del, 0s), var(--t-del, 0s), var(--o-del, 0s), var(--h-del, 0s);
}
/**/

.rotation {
  --t-dur: 0.4s;
}

.linear {
  --l-dur: 0.8s;
  --b-dur: 0.8s;
}

.grow {
  --h-dur: 1s;
}

.show {
  --o-dur: 0.5s;
  --o-del: 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorthand class combining all of what you need is the following:

```
  .linear-rotation {
    transition: left 0.8s, bottom 0.8s, transform 0.4s;
  }
```